# Lambda function to start instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tags, aws-lambda

[image]I need a lambda function to start all the instances with a tag called ServerType and different values associated with different instances. The lambda function tries to look for all the tags and consider to be present on every instance. So it is working in AND operator. I want it to work in OR operator and turn or all the instances which are tagged with the ServerType tag. How do I do it? Tags are written in the filter function.

Comment: Please replace your picture with a text version of the code so that it is searchable. You can indent the text to make it printable (or select it and his Ctrl-K to indent).

Comment: The problem is that you are misinterpreting how the "Filter" query works inside the API, it only works in an AND format meaning that all of those values/tags need to be evaluated to be True, as John said if you remove `filter` and get all instances then filter from there your life will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to remove the `filter` and obtain a list of **all instances**.

Then, you can filter the list in your code with whatever logic you wish.